# Passing Parameters Into WebView for OAuth 2.0

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement OAuth 2.0 for an app I am building. We are following draft 25 here http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-25.pdf.

I have got the client_id and secret from the server but I need to pass this into a webview so the user can sign in and give permission. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really simple but having now idea about web technologies I was a little lost. I needed to modify the URL with a ?, then the param name, then an =, then the param value.

Like so

```
 String url = "https://staging.doo.net/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + creds.clientId + "&redirect_uri=doo%3A%2F%2Fauthorize";
```